# Eclipse crashes on Ubuntu 14.04: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"

Tags: java, eclipse, gtk, ubuntu-14.04

Eclipse Juno crashes within minutes of launching. I have expanded the allocated memory and searched here for additional help - it seems to be a common problem but the solutions suggested don't work.

I get this error message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

... then many lines of...

```
(npviewer.bin:3295): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

... and then:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc89b2542a1, pid=3155, tid=140502262986496
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.4
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/adteclipse/eclipse/hs_err_pid3155.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** ERROR: rpc_end_sync called when not in sync!
```

This problem is described in answers to other questions as an issue with themes. The thing is, I already installed the ones that trigger this problem. I installed gtk2-engines, gtk-murrine-engine, gtk-equinox-engine, libgtkmm, libcanberra-gtk-module and as many themes. So for some reason the system is not finding them.

I also tweaked with eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dorg.jboss.tools.vpe.loadxulrunner=false
```

I also tried putting

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

in place of the last line. No joy; Eclipse keeps crashing within minutes. What else could I check?

Comment: Are `gtk2-engines-murrine` and `overlay-scrollbar` packages installed?

Comment: Can you paste `/usr/local/adteclipse/eclipse/hs_err_pid3155.log`?

Comment: The log file was too long to paste in, but I posted it on Pastebin - here's a link: http://pastebin.com/3jmSRNSV

Comment: I've got the same issue, IMHO after installing some ubuntu updates...

Comment: This bug is defined here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1262022 and here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1134202